# Get string as is even when it contains a newline character

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary with the following values

```
"key1" = "abc\ndef"
"key2" = "1234568"
```

Get value from dictionary

```
NSString *myString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"key1"];
```

If I output "myString" in the debugger I get

```
abc
def
```

So how do I get the value from the dictionary so that "myString" will output

```
abc\ndef
```

just like it is in the dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The string contains a newline and that is what `po myString` shows. Printing a *dictionary* escapes all non-ASCII characters, so the newline is printed as `\n`.

Comment: Correct. My question was a brainfart on my end by thinking I was seeing a problems was there was none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before output in debugger you can escape newline characters:

```
NSString *myString = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"key1"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
```

It will be printed with "\n".

Comment: My problem was a brainfart, but I did not even think about trying this.  Thanks!